# Form submitting after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with this validation javascript.
Js check if value is selected. If both dropdown options sare elected form is sent.

But send not working. What's wrong?

Thanks all ;-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function (e) {
   if($('#species').find(":selected").val()===""){
     //alert("empty");
     $("#msg1").html("Required");

   }    
   if($('#species2').find(":selected").val()===""){
     //alert("empty2");
     $("#msg2").html("Requires");

   }
   e.preventDefault()
});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form  method="post" action="send.php">
<label for="species" id="bobo">*Species:</label><br />

<div id="msg1"></div>
<select id="species" name="species" size="1">
<option value="">Please choose a species</option>
<option value="21">Chicken</option>
<option value="28">Turkey</option>
</select>

<br />

<div id="msg2"></div>
<select id="species2" name="species2" size="1">
<option value="">Please choose a species2</option>
<option value="21">Chicken</option>
<option value="28">Turkey</option>
</select>

<br />


<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: when you say send not working... what do you mean? what does your console say is the error? does your network tab have a request actually being fired? we can help you but you have to help us help u

Comment: First of all. That's not helpful in the slightest bit. luckily i think that i know the answer

Comment: @iAmClownShoe - I disagree with you, entirely - he may not have used JS diction, but his response stated that the form will not submit and implied that there were no errors. Were that not the case, i.e. were those implications unintentional, no one would be able to "know the answer".

Comment: sometimes we have to stop discussing since we are not fluent in English, but some people seem to not understand this ... Thanks Zachary.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should attach a `submit` event to the `form` element, because it's possible to send the form without clicking the Submit button.

i.e. (assuming you give an id of `form` to your form):

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) { ... });
```

Secondly, when you call `e.preventDefault()`, it cancels the action, thus not submitting the form.

Put `e.preventDefault()` in the `if` statements if there is an error, so it *only* is called if there is an error.

Comment: I said, "(assuming you give an id of form to your form)." I didn't want him to bind it to all forms ever!

Comment: Ooooh - hahaha sorry about that :) I removed the comment

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `$("form").submit()` call after validating that the two values are selected.

In other words, you never made the call you submit the form. You should put this right after the last check and move the `e.preventDefault()` to be the first line in the click-handler function's body.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button in your html is what will fire the httprequest to your action. but in your javascript you use `e.preventDefault()`. this will prevent the html default behavior from submitting your serialized form data. You are going to need to use ajax if you want to run javascript validation first and then submit the form after it's been validated. Otherwise the submit button will automatically submit whatever you have in the form and redirect you to the action as defined in the html element.